# how can i improve performance on github pages?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages, cdn

i'm hosting a page built on react on github pages, my problem is that im displaying a video and  it affects performance. Should i buy a cdn to serve videos or images, or i should change server and still serving static content? The cdn would help or github pages it's slow anyway ?

Answer (score 2):

How are you embedding the video? If you embed the video via Youtube it should select a quality low enough to suit faster loading times, otherwise you can try lazy-loading=true in the video tag, and maybe async if you're pulling it from another source. Otherwise you'll find the most impact in performance is to limit the amount of data the client has to download by compressing the video.

Comment: i'm just importing it  ```import Video from '../../video/video2.mp4';
            <StyledVideo src={Video} autoPlay muted loop  />
``` i'll try lazy load and async thanks.

Comment: I think in you're case then you should compress the video, that'll have much more impact than async and lazy-loading combined. Especially if the video appears above-the-fold (at the top of the page), it's going to have to load anyway. Try to compress the video with reducing the file size as much as possible while retaining most of the quality in mind. There are online resources to do this, or you can get more customized with HandBrake (although I prefer to use a website for small videos).